# CharsetDecoder does not decode the number

Tags: java, utf-8, decode, utf8-decode

I have code:

```
byte[] str = new byte[17];

str[0] = 115; //s
str[1] = 121; //y
str[2] = 112; //p
str[3] = 105; //i
str[4] = 49; //current UnixTime numbers
str[5] = 52;
str[6] = 49;
str[7] = 50;
str[8] = 49;
str[9] = 49;
str[10] = 51;
str[11] = 51;
str[12] = 50;
str[13] = 57;
str[14] = 52;
str[15] = 49;
str[16] = 50;


 CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(2048);
 ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(str);

 Charset ch = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
 CharsetDecoder cd = ch.newDecoder();
CoderResult cr = cd.decode(buf, cb, true);
cb.flip();
System.out.println("!"+cb.toString()+"!");
```

But getting into the console only

> sypi

- System.out.println(bb.array().length); //17
- Tried

  cd.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
  cd.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);

Excuse my English.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile at the moment. Shouldn't you have a `CharBuffer` somewhere? Ideally, post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Works for me, after adding a CharBuffer. I would guess that your CharBuffer cb, wherever you declare that, is too small. In that case you will get `OVERFLOW` as the CoderResult, which means the charset converter needs to be called again to finish the job.

Comment: Why not just `String test = new String( str, "UTF-8" );`?  What are you trying to show here?

Comment: Fixed complete program.

Comment: Try inserting a `cd.flush(cb);` after the decode call (?). Also what CoderResult do you get?

Comment: String test = new String( str, "UTF-8" );
Work. Thx you!

Comment: I needed cb.clear();

Comment: Use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` and `new String(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead of `new String(str, "UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program works for me.  It's basically the same thing as your corrected example.

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
           throws Exception
   {
      byte[] str = new byte[ 17 ];

      str[0] = 115; //s
      str[1] = 121; //y
      str[2] = 112; //p
      str[3] = 105; //i
      str[4] = 49; //current UnixTime numbers
      str[5] = 52;
      str[6] = 49;
      str[7] = 50;
      str[8] = 49;
      str[9] = 49;
      str[10] = 51;
      str[11] = 51;
      str[12] = 50;
      str[13] = 57;
      str[14] = 52;
      str[15] = 49;
      str[16] = 50;

      String test = new String( str, "UTF-8" );
      System.out.println( test );

      ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap( str );

      Charset ch = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );
      CharsetDecoder cd = ch.newDecoder();
      CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.allocate( 1024 );
      CoderResult cr = cd.decode( buf, cbuf, true );
      System.out.println("\"?"+cr+"?\"");

      cbuf.flip();

      System.out.println( "!" + cbuf.toString() + "!" );
   }
```

Output:

```
run:
sypi1412113329412
"?UNDERFLOW?"
!sypi1412113329412!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```